# Docker commands for installing SQL server driver

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have deployed my first classic asp application to Docker container.now i am trying to set up db connection for testing.i have db connection test page but its throwing error seems like SQL driver not installed in the windows container.Can any body help on this ,is there any commands for installing SQL driver in the container. Find the docker file which i used.

```
FROM microsoft/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2016
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-ASP

COPY ./share/ClassicAspApp.zip

RUN Expand-Archive -Path ClassicAspApp.zip -DestinationPath C:\ClassicAspApp; `
    Remove-Item ClassicAspApp.zip

RUN Remove-Website -
```